# Outlook wouldn't show latest emails after company has moved to gmail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

My company has just started using gmail instead of outlook but please note that the company's email domain is still the same so we login to gmail.com using our i@company.com email address.

I can see that i don't receive any emails in my outlook now. I would like to configure my i@company.com account in outlook even though its using gmail (i guess google servers now?)

How can i do this? I would like to configure this not just in my Windows but also in my android phone as the stock android email client has stopped receiving emails after the migration.

I have tried to add my account to outlook in a fresh VM but it only updates till the migration date and doesn't show the latest emails.

Please advise.

Comment: Why do you think an internet community will know better what to do than your company helpdesk or IT administrators? Ask them for proper configuration.

Comment: Because i dont think its configuration related, any email can be configured in outlook and this is no different. All i want to know is what am i missing here, i have added all my personal and work related email addresses in a single outlook installation and using add account feature. All i had to do was add email address and password and the outlook will automatiically figure out the server settings.

Comment: Found the issue

Comment: @irish, if you keep it a secret, what you learned won't help anyone else with a similar problem.  Can you post an answer with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not enable imap by default - you'd need to log into the webui and explicitly allow it. Its covered in their support page. go click on the gear icon, go to settings, and go to forwarding and pop/imap and set it appropriately. You can find the configuration there as well.

[image: ts covered in their support page] -

Comment: This tab "Forwarding" doesn't show anything for us as it has been disabled by the admin.

Comment: In which case you really should talk to your admin about enabling imap access